# VirtualBox host-only network, ping works only from guest to host

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a Windows 7 VM running on a Ubuntu 15.04 host using the latest Virtual Box 5 release.
I've configured a host-only network. 
The configuration of the host-only adapter is:

```
Adapter IP 192.168.56.1
        Subnetmask 255.255.255.0
DHCP enabled
        Server 192.168.56.100
        Mask 255.255.255.0
        from 192.168.56.101
        to 192.168.56.254
```

With the adapter being created by VirtualBox, `ifconfig vboxnet0` displays:

```
vboxnet0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0a:00:27:00:00:00  
          inet addr:192.168.56.1  Bcast:192.168.56.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::800:27ff:fe00:0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:960 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:112330 (112.3 KB)
```

The Windows 7 guest receives an IP from the DHCP Server and also seem to have a properly configured interface:

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::18e1:2f8e:907a:e280%11
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.101
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

The issue I'm currently facing is that I **can** ping the Ubuntu host from the Windows 7 guest using `ping 192.168.56.1`. However, I **can't** ping the guest using `ping 192.168.56.101` from my host system. Wireshark tells me that echo requests are sent just fine, but there are no replies coming back. The guest system is a fresh installed Windows 7.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This could be a firewall issue. The Windows 7 firewall blocks ICMP echo requests by default. Try to disable the firewall or to add an exception rule for ICMP echo requests.

Comment: Thanks. Disabling the firewall actually solved the problem. I never thought that the Windows firewall would block a simple ping by default.